# /me/accounts returns empty

Tags: php, facebook, api

I've had access token problems for a while, and I thought that was solved by putting in a try-catch syntax. Unfortunately all it did was hide the error, and there will still be times that /me/accounts will return empty. Here's my code:

```
if($facebook->getUser()==0) {
    header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'SCOPE'))}");
} else {
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    if ($user) {
        $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'scope' => 'SCOPE'
        ));
    }
    try {
        $access_token=$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
        $accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');            
        .
        .
        .
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        $results = $e->getResult();
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell me why my code generates an empty array at times?

Comment: what is me/accounts supposed to return? A link to documentation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

After looking through developer blog on Facebook, i came across this:

> Removing apps from /me/accounts/ 
>   We will no longer show apps under /me/accounts/ in the Graph API. You can access the list of apps a user is a developer on by hitting /me/applications/developer/.

(you can find whole list of changes [here](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/12/05/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

So the reason you're getting empty array might be that /me/accounts is no longer supported.

Also, when making api call that takes requires access token, you should pass it like this:

```
$facebook->setExtendedAccessToken();
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken()
$facebook->api('/me/accounts', 'GET', array(
               'access_token' => $access_token));
```

Comment: just read it, and i don't think this is an issue, since im accessing pages on /me/accounts instead of apps anyway.

also, i think that /me/accounts will still be supported, but the "apps" value on /me/accounts won't.

Comment: You are welcome! Check developers blog from time to time, it might save you a lot of pain in future!

Comment: Also, i noticed that you are not getting the access token (setExtended...) doesn't return token as far as i know. I edited my answer to show how to get the token and use it to make a call to API

Comment: It does, actually. So we don't have to call getAccessToken() :)